# systemctl chrome-remote-desktop without superuser

Tags: permissions, google-chrome, systemd

Some time ago to enable chrome remote desktop it was necessary to insert the user in the chrome-remote-desktop group to prevent the user from having to be a super user to enable the service

Now the user needs to have super users permission to enable the execution of bin/systemctl

I'm trying unsuccessfully to allow any user to enable chrome-remote-desktop without the authentication box indicated in the photo below appearing.

I tried to edit `/etc/sudoers` `ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl` with no success either so the login box doesn't appear anymore and also through the linux terminal

[image]

NOTE: the operating system accessed is a ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Off the top of my head, doesn't `systemctl --user` run the service under the current user instead of root? e.g., `systemctl --user start chrome-remote-desktop` Have you already tried this?

Comment: Hi @mcid the return is "Failed to start chrome-remote-desktop.service: Unit chrome-remote-desktop.service not found". But I would need to be able to get this authentication box off when the user enables remote access